# Why use floats instead of css property table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have started using the"display:table" property in CSS to properly structure my html5 elements, and it works great.

Can someone tell my why using floats is better? Ironically, it seems like this is the future? It's easy, simple and understandable?

Comment: most of the coder use divs instead of tables that's why they use floats.

Comment: Probably because `display:table` is not supported by older browsers, specifically older versions of IE.

Comment: @newuser I'm not using tables as markup?

Comment: @shanethehat Sure, but if you dont care about those users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as a table layout works for you, you can use it.

However, it would be a good idea to make yourself familiar with other ways to control the layout. As soon as you want to do something that doesn't fit in the strict grid that a table forces upon you, you need to use something completely different.

Comment: Sure, but is it a good way? I can always use a table as my base?

Comment: @JamesFord: A table layout is more limiting than an floating layout, but as long as don't have any problems with the limitations, it would work well.

Answer (score -1):

it would be a good idea to make yourself familiar with other ways to control the layout. As soon as you want to do something that doesn't fit in the strict grid that a table forces upon you, you need to use something completely different.